# Bind a subreport Inside Each Table Row in a Crystal Report

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010

I am using crystal reports 2008 to display data in a table using .net. I need to display last column value based on each table rows' few values and need to query that result and bind in table last column.This last column I used a sub report. I can bind the command in to dataset with out last column sub report.

I need how to bind this last column data, do I need to go through a loop and one by one bind the dataset in to sub report or else another way?

I would like to know how to bind this Command3 object in crystal report sub report in design view as well. Because it is dynamic and querying inside a loop.

Here is my tried code.

```
'main report set dataset
    report.SetDataSource(DS)

    'sub report
    Dim mySubReport As ReportDocument
    mySubReport = report.OpenSubreport("cash_flow.rpt")

    Dim DA_Dynamic As New OracleDataAdapter
    Dim DS_Dynamic As New DataSet

    For Each DataRow As DataRow In DS.Tables(0).Rows

        Dim Command_3 As String = "select .....command by passing main table dataset each row parameters"
        Dim mycomm_Dynamic As OracleCommand = New OracleCommand(Command_3, myconn)
        mycomm_Dynamic.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        DA_Dynamic.SelectCommand = mycomm_Dynamic
        DA_Dynamic.Fill(DS_Dynamic, "Command_3")

        report.Subreports(DS.Tables(0).Rows.IndexOf(DataRow)).SetDataSource(DS_Dynamic.Tables(0))
    Next

    Me.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = report
    'CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
    myconn.Dispose()
    DS.Dispose()
    DA.Dispose()
```

Comment: what's in the subreport?

Comment: The result coming from first dataset DS.According to the first DS I need to pass few parameters in row by row in order to get dataset(DS_Dynamic) for the subreport.sub report is preparing based on that DS_Dynamic dataset.

Comment: Actaully the sub query return a list in order to bind in to last column of the main table.